# change Module position in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I am working on a website using Joomla, how can I change Module position in the picture below

[click to see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8S8p.png)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since most menus do not allow a search bar to show without it being a drop down item or part of a mega menu, your best bet would be to remove the float:right line of code so it just starts from that left side.